# convert bytes to bits with leading zeros

Tags: python, format, byte

I know that i can do this :

```
byte = 58

format ( byte , '08b' )


>>> '00111010'
```

with two bytes i have to do

`format( bytes , '016b')`

but if i doesn't have the number of bytes i can't set a number for format
so i have to do :

```
with open('file','rb')as a:
    b = a.read()
    c = int.from_bytes ( b )
    d = format( c ,'b')
d = (8-len(a)%8)*'0'+d
```

but i was wondering if there was easier way to do this
and i want this without using any loops

thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you want the entire file contents presented as a bit string?

Comment: Yes! And with leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map each byte to an 8-bit representation with the `str.format` method and then join the byte representations into a single string for output (where `b` is the bytes object you read from a file):

```
print(''.join(map('{:08b}'.format, b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you want the entire file content printed as a bit string.

If so, you could do this:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'rb') as bdata:
    print(''.join(f'{b:08b}' for b in bdata.read()))
```

...or...

```
with open('foo.txt', 'rb') as bdata:
    for b in bdata.read():
        print(f'{b:08b}', end='')
print()
```

...which will use less memory

...or...

```
def _format(b):
    return format(b, '08b')

with open('foo.txt', 'rb') as bdata:
    print(''.join(map(_format, bdata.read())))
```

...which avoids explicit loops at the risk of using too much memory

Comment: Thanks but i knew this . I want to make it directly not with for loops.

Comment: There is **nothing** in your question about avoiding explicit loops. Please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sys.getsizeof()

```
import sys

byte = 58
num_bytes = sys.getsizeof(byte)
binary_string = format(byte, f'0{num_bytes*8}b')
```

or

```
byte = 58
num_bytes = (byte.bit_length() + 7) // 8
binary_string = format(byte, f'0{num_bytes*8}b')
```

and if that doesnt work

```
byte = 58
num_bytes = (byte.bit_length() + 7) // 8
byte_string = byte.to_bytes(num_bytes, byteorder='big')
binary_string = ''.join(format(b, '08b') for b in byte_string)
```